# Allow root user to login on ftp

Tags: ftp, centos, ftp-client

I am setting up FTP on CentOS.

I want client to login in server with username : root.

For that, I modified /etc/vsftpd/ftpusers and commented root.

But even after that(over rebooting as well), my client is unable to login FTP server with username root.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your vsftpd config file
userlist_enbale=YES

Then edit user_list and ftpusers it should work since you have already commented out root in this file.